# How can I refresh all families of an always-alive provider manually in riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

**I have used family to cache all data.**

```
final provider =
    StateNotifierProvider.family((ref, data) => ListNotifier(ref, data));
```

**I want to refresh all families of these providers.**

my provider receives an object and returns the same type of object.
An object has a generic type of list which is the same type of object.
I update every single thing in my nested objects. but, now I have to need to refresh all family providers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remi Rousselet [answered](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/1628) this question